# What is this type of graph called? $y=\frac{x-3}{x^2+9x-22}$

Tags: terminology, graphing-functions

the teacher told us to draw a graph from a function and I was having a hard time until I graphed it out on Desmos. This is the output:

[Picture of the graph (the site won't let me upload the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEkJh.png)

The teacher never taught us about a graph that splits like that and the only graph I know that splits similarly is Tan from trigonometry.

My question is what is the name of this type of graph and how do we know it is drawn like that without using any graphing calculator. Apologies for the bad english as it is not my main language. Thank you

Edit:
What I meant by *this type* is, for example:

- If the graph is U shaped, then it is a graph of a quadratic function
- If the graph is a line, then it is a graph of a linear function.

I think the more correct wording for the question is What is the term used to call this graph?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Unfortunately, your question isn’t well defined. What do you mean by *this type*? Plus, the post is not complete and freestanding because it cannot be read without following the link, which could at some point be unreachable. If you don’t edit your post to clear up these problems, then it’s likely to be closed.

Comment: Have you never seen the graph of $\frac1x$ before? I think you should start with that one. I would actually suggest you draw it by hand, for $x$ between $-1$ and $1$. Take extra care for $x$-values closer to $0$. @PaulTanenbaum Those aren't discontinuities. They are points where the function isn't defined. That's entirely different.

Comment: D’oh! You’re right, @Arthur. I’ve nuked that comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will edit the post once I get home to make it clearer

Comment: Take a look at "fractional-rational function". Depending on the degree (deg) of the numerator (=N) and denominator (=D), the graph looks differently as x approaches infinity. search for examples where deg(N) > deg(D), deg(N) < deg(D) and also deg(N) = deg(D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions of the form $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials, are called *rational functions*, just like how numbers of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers are called rational numbers.

To know what the graph of a rational function will look like, some of the features include:

- If $p(x)$ has a zero (and $q(x)$ doesn't), then $f(x)$ will have a zero at the same point.
- If $q(x)$ has a zero (and $p(x)$ doesn't), then $f(x)$ will have a vertical asymptote at that point.
- You can perform polynomial division to determine the leading behaviour of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $\pm \infty$. For example, $x^2 + 9x - 22 = (x-3)(x+12) + 14$, so as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$, $\frac{x-3}{x^2 + 9x - 22}$ will start to look like the graph of $\frac{1}{x+12}$.